# browser-sync opens without css

Tags: html, css, browser-sync

I'm very new to coding and this is my very first time asking a question here, so if i get something wrong, I'm sorry.
I was trying to set up browser-sync for the first time, but when i start it, it my html file without css, even though the styles are there and when i double click the index.html file, it opens perfectly. [image: Here's what i type out to the terminal and also the location of the project folder i'm trying to open]

I've tried doing what all the tutorials say and going into the right directory first and then starting the browser-sync